# Dimension of an eigenspace, discrepancy

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
    4       & 1 & -1 \\
    2       & 5 & -2 \\
    1       & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

And the eigenvalues 5, 3, 3.

The eigenspace with eigenvalue 3 has dimension 2 (rank 1). No doubt.

However, for eigenvalue 5, $A-5I$ has rank 2. Till that point I agree with my professor’s solution. But shouldn’t the dimension of the eigenspace be $3-2 = 1$? According to my textbook, the dimension is 2.

Comment: The dimension of the eigenspace is at most equal to the (algebraic) multiplicity of the eigenvalue it is associated to. Therefore, simple eigenvalues (i.e., roots of the characteristic polynomial of multiplicity 1), will always have an eigenspace of dimension 1.

Comment: Meaning I am right and the dimension is 1?

Comment: The eigenspace with eigenvalue $3$ is $2$-dimensional, spanned by $(1,0,1)$ and $(-1,1,0)$

Comment: Yes but the eigenspace of the eigenvalue 3 has dimension 2. The matrix is diagonalizable

Comment: Sorry, in my question I meant rank 1 and dimension 2, ill edit it now.

Comment: What did you discover about $A-5I$? It should have a one-dimensional kernel, in other words it should be of rank two, as you have written.

Comment: Exactly, and therefore the dimension of he eigenspace is 1. My math book said 2.